# Not sure why the geodesic derivation equation involved second ordinary derivative

Tags: tensors

My question is related to this link (18:10)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQZTYt_Pxcc&list=PLJHszsWbB6hpk5h8lSfBkVrpjsqvUGTCx&index=28

Recently i have watched a video about volume derivation.
In this video,the presenter tried to relate the ordinary derivative of the Volume to the Ricci tensor but i get stuck when i try to understand it.

My problem is i dont understand why $\ddot{S^{\mu_j} _j} $
is equal to $ -R^{\mu_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z v^x$ at 18:10

The reason why
$\ddot{S^{\mu_j} _j} $
should not be equal to 
$ -R^{\mu_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z y^x$
where $$[\nabla_v\nabla_vS]^{\mu^j}= -R^{\mu_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z v^x $$ is because they are different things.
The former is just second ordinary derivative and the latter is the full-form second covariant derivative.

i cannot see why it is not second ordinary derivative since volume itself a scalar.
if you take derivative of the volume with ordinary derivative,then the logic should follow in a similar manner and the second derivative of the vector component 
(part of the decomposition because of product rule) should be the ordinary type derivative

I would now give an example why they are not equal.

Given a 2D-Volume(area) which is spanned by vector $\vec{A} $ and $\vec{B}$, we can take the derivative:

The volume is $ V=\epsilon_{kj} A^kB^j$.
If you take the ordinary derivative of the volume $$\dfrac {dV} {d\lambda}=\epsilon_{jk} [\dfrac{dB^j}{d\lambda}]A^k\epsilon_{jk} [\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda}]B^j$$

and this implies you will take the ordinary derivative of [$A^k$](as a result of product rule) which is $$\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda} $$
however this is just part of the $\nabla_vA$:

$[∇vA]^k=\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda}[1.]+v^j\gamma^{k}_{ij}$[2]=$v^j\dfrac{dA^k}{dx^j} + v^j\gamma^{k}_{ij}$

where$\gamma^{k}_{ij} $is the connection factor that is missed out and $ v^j \dfrac{d}{dx^j}$ is equal to $\frac{d}{d\lambda}$.

It is shown that the ordinary derivative of $A^i$ is just[1.]and[2] is neglected.
[1.] is just the ordinary derivative part of the volume derivation
[2] is the whole derivative which includes connection factor
it is clear that [1.] is not equal to [2].
Therefore$[∇vA]^k$ is not equal to $\dfrac{dA^k}{d\lambda}$   .
Follow the similar line of reasoning,i think  $\ddot{S^{\mu_j} _j} $=$\dfrac{d^2(s^{\mu_j})}{d\lambda^2}$ should not be equal to$[\nabla_v\nabla_vS]^{\mu^j}$ ,i am not sure why they are equal

$\ddot{S^{\mu_j} _j}$= $\dfrac{d^2(s^{\mu_j})}{d\lambda^2}$=?? $[∇_v∇_vS]^{\mu_j}= R^{\mu_j}{}_{xyz}  s^y_j v^z v^x$

could anyone help me please

Here is my picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn37y.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Pleae don't use `$$...$$` for each and every mathematical expression, such as $\gamma_{ij}^k$. It makes the text hard to read.

Comment: Sorry.What do i need to do?  i need to express the whole equation in  other form?

Comment: If you want to type $\gamma_{ij}^k$, then simply type `$\gamma_{ij}^k$`.

Comment: i see. thank you for your reminding .

Comment: I don't quite understand the relevance of $\dfrac{dV} {d\lambda} $. So $\dfrac{dV} {d\lambda} = \dfrac{\epsilon_{ij} A^i A^j} {d\lambda} = \epsilon_{ij} \left(\dfrac{dA^i} {d\lambda} A^j+ A^i \dfrac{dA^j} {d\lambda}\right)  $. What's the problem?

Comment: $= \epsilon_{ij} \dfrac{dA^i} {d\lambda} A^j+\epsilon_{ij} A^i \dfrac{dA^j} {d\lambda} =  \epsilon_{ij} \dfrac{dA^i} {d\lambda} A^j+\epsilon_{ji} A^j \dfrac{dA^i} {d\lambda} =(\epsilon_{ij} -\epsilon_{ij}) \dfrac{dA^i} {d\lambda} A^j = 0$

Comment: You cannot define $V = \epsilon_{ijk} A^iB^j$ since indices do not match. You have an additional index $k$ on the right...

Comment: I think probably the answer is that the left hand side is in fact $\left(\dfrac {d^2\vec S_j} {d\lambda^2} \right) ^{\mu_j} = (\ddot{\vec S_j})   ^{\mu_j} $ and not $\dfrac{d^2S_j^{\mu_j}} {d\lambda^2} $

Comment: i think so,but i don't understand why they are different.

Comment: since it is actually the second ordinary derivative of S (it is because they take the ordinary second derivative of the volume)

Comment: it seems the presenter is not correct to set $\ddot{S^{u_j} _j}= [∇v∇vS]^{uj}$as they are different object.(i am not sure??may be he is correct)

the former one is just part of the product:  $\dfrac{dV}{d\lambda} =\epsilon_{ijk} deg(\sqrt(g))[\dfrac{dS^{u_i} _i}{d\lambda}]S^{u_j} _j$



and this $[\dfrac{dS^{u_i} _i}{d\lambda}]$ is not equal to$ [∇vS]^{ui}$

if this is not the same,then i think the second order derivative one would not be the same as well :(

Comment: They don't involve the derivative of basis vector ,therefore there is no connection coefficient involved.